# AJAX: Post the Form details without page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Created a HTML page with form field, while hitting form, the form details posted in other domain Market site.

```
<form  method="Post"  action="http://app-o.marketo.com/index.php/leadCapture/save"  name="mktForm_6" id="mktForm_6">

    <label>First Name:</label><span class='mktInput'><input  name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='1' />

    <label>Email Address:</label><input  name="Email" id="Email" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='2'`enter code here` />

    <label>Subscription</label><input class='mktFormHidden' name="Subscription_Expiration__c" id="Subscription_Expiration__c" type='hidden' value="Newsletter Subscription" />
    <input id='mktFrmSubmit' type='submit' style="width: auto; overflow: visible; padding-left: .25em; padding-right: .25em;" value='Submit'  />

    <input type="hidden" name="lpId" value="1030" />

    <input type="hidden" name="subId" value="123" />

    <input type="hidden" name="searchstr" value="" />

    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="6" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_mkt_disp" value="return" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_mkt_trk" value="id:668-TIV-019&token:_mch-syncfusion.com-1350287989102-87089" />

</form>
```

But now I want to post the form details via AJAX, because normal form post refresh the page.

Can anyone suggest how to post the details in `$.post()` method of AJAX with clear details?

Comment: i request you to read jquery ajax ($.ajax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet, and how would `$.ajax` help to POST form data to another domain?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
var data = { Firstname: $("#firstnametxt")[0].value, Email: $("#txtemail")[0].value};}
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveCustomer","Customer")',
    data: jsondata,
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (_results, status, message) {
       $("#Targetdiv").html(_results);
    },
    error: function (_results, status, message) {

    }
});
```

Have a View model similar to this.

```
public class Customer
{
    public String FirstName{get;set;}
    public String Email{get;set;}

}
```

And receive the data in controller like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCustomer(Customer _Customer)
{
    //Receive the posted json data as your view model object(_Customer) here
    //Asp.net translate the same for you.
}
```

**If You are using IE use json2.js which is available [Here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js])**

Comment: He wants to POST the form to another site (a different domain). `$.ajax` won't help in this case.